# add a "Image popup" in a seperate "div" when hovering over a link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make it so that when I hover over one of my 4 links on my project page that an image I created will pop up on a separate part of the page within a scrollbox.

So for example. Each one of my links has a separate class (see below).
When I hover over each class, I am trying to make a image pop up (which is easy enough)
however I want it to pop up in a separate div.

```
            <div style="height:95px;width:345px;overflow:hidden;background-image:url('KAIROS-port-final-i-hope_03.jpg');"> 
            <center>
            Content! 
        </center></div>

<style>
  .lefteye {
    width:107px;
    height:66px;
    display:block;
    background-image: url('lefteyewithnoanimation');
  }
  .lefteye:hover {
    background-image: url('lefteye.jpg');
  }
</style>
```

is an example of 1 of my links setup already.
the image changes, but im not sure how I want to approach having something pop up elsewhere inside the scrollbox. Im thinking give it a "class" then add something to .lefteye:hover

is this possible? if so any ideas?

Comment: https://ibb.co/WzJnrNN

I am including an image to explain it better.
when I hover over a body part... a new background image appears (these are links). In the white field, is kind of a "thought bubble" and I want to code it to display "what the link is exactly" 

so link 1 (about me)
linke 2 (etc)
and so on.

Comment: You can add the image by clicking edit on your post and paste the link there. Also, whenever possible, try inserting a working snippet in your question by pressing `Ctrl+M` when you're editing your post or click on the `JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet` icon.